# How to get Access Point Name programmatically

Tags: android, apn

I'm trying to get **Access Point Name** programmatically.I need this to develop application for the specific APN name.I googled lot but didn't find any proper way can any tell me how to do this.Thanks

Comment: @Triode I believe APN here states for `Access Point Name`, not Application name...

Comment: @Triode Asking about APN name NOT application name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Selected APN:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"), null, null, null, null);
```

For All APN Names:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/current"), null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

For All APN Names:

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/current"),null, null, null, null);
        Log.e("MainActivity","getColumnNames: "+ 
                        Arrays.toString(c.getColumnNames())); //get the column names from here.
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")); //one of the column name to get the APN names.
                Log.e("MainActivity","data: "+ data);

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
```

For Selected APN:

```
Cursor c1 = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"),null, null, null, null);
    if (c1.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String data = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("name"));
            Log.e("MainActivity","data: "+ data);
        }while(c1.moveToNext());
    }
    c1.close();
```

Comment: Don't forget the permission WRITE_APN_SETTINGS in the manifest, even if you are just reading.